# Set specific div contenteditable to true on button click using Javascript (MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am populating divs with data in it by use of a foreach :

```
@foreach (var item in Model.EmploymentDetailsList)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-user bg-aqua"></i>
                            <div class="timeline-item">
                                <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Current</span>
                                <h3 class="timeline-header">@item.Position at <a href="@item.EmploymentCompanyWebsite">@item.EmploymentCompany</a></h3>
                                <div id="page-wrapper">
                                    <section>
                                        <div id="editor" class="diveditor timeline-body">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="pkiEmploymentDetailID" value="@item.pkiEmploymentDetailID" />
                                            @Html.Raw(item.PositionDetails)
                                        </div>
                                    </section>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-footer">
                                    <button id="editorBtn" type="button" class="edit-button btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</button>
                                    @*<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a>*@
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                                            <!-- timeline time label -->
                        <li class="time-label">
                            <span class="bg-red">
                                @item.StartDate
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    <!-- /.timeline-label -->
                    }
```

And I have the following JS that I am trying to use to set the specific div's contenteditable to true, based on the button clicked in that div :

```
<script>
        //var editorBtn = document.getElementById('editorBtn');
        //var element = document.getElementById('editor');

        $('.edit-button').on('click', function () {
        //editorBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault();
            //alert("Button Clicked");

            if ($('.diveditor').attr('contenteditable', 'false')) {
                // Disable Editing
                //This code runs when you click Save
                alert("Button Editable works");
                //alert(element.innerHTML);

                //TODO: Do Ajax call to save content to  Database
                var ProfileDetails =
               {
                   "EmploymentDetails": element.innerHTML
               };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Profile/Save_Employment/',
                    data: JSON.stringify(ProfileDetails),
                    datatype: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.diveditor').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
                        $('.edit-button').innerHTML = 'Edit';
                        // You could save any changes here.
                    }
                });


            } else {
                //This code runs when you click Edit
                $('.diveditor').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
                $('.edit-button').innerHTML = 'Save';
                $('.diveditor').focus();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

So as you will see, all the Div's and buttons have the same names and I would like to edit only the specific Div that I click the button on(the edit button) - I have done something similar using a webgrid by using the class name.

Currently it sets focus to the last Div and not the one I want. It also does not change the button from "Edit" to "Save".

Is there a better way of doing this ? Or can someone possibly help me with what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Use relative selectors - `var contentDiv - $(this).closest('.timeline-item').find('.diveditor');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `data-` attributes to tell your script, which element should be now editable and give every div his own `id` attribute like this.

```
<div id="editor_@item.pkiEmploymentDetailID" class="diveditor timeline-body">
    <input type="hidden" class="pkiEmploymentDetailID" value="@item.pkiEmploymentDetailID" />
   @Html.Raw(item.PositionDetails)
</div>

<button id="editorBtn" type="button" class="edit-button btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-edit="@item.pkiEmploymentDetailID">Edit</button>
```

and in your jQuery script you know which element was clicked if you're passing argument to click handler. With this information you can read `data-edit` and make specific div editable.

```
$('.edit-button').on('click', function (event) {
    var clicked = $(event.target);
    var editableId = "editor_" + clicked.data("edit");
    // make element with id=editableId editable

    if ($('#'+editableId).attr('contenteditable', 'false')) {
        /* code */
    }
    else
    {
        $('#'+editableId).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
        clicked.html('Save');
        $('#'+editableId).focus();
    }
}
```

This approach allows you to change your HTML structure without worrying about breaking something in your JS.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I tried this but I have 2 problems. 1. clicked returns undefined. 2. It goes into the If statement even though the contenteditable value is not false(false = its not currently editable)

Comment: I made a mistake - in `if` you should use `$('#'+editableId)`. As for first problem - that's weird, [I just created JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak7tg151/) and it seems to work.

Comment: Let me relook at my code, maybe I am missing something. Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: Can you explain what this part is doing : clicked.data("id") ?

Comment: Well, it supposed to be `.data("edit")` - I'm sorry I wrote the answer and then changed some names. `.data()` allows you to read [`data-` attributes values](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/). In this case it would read value of `data-id` (which in this example would be incorrect)

Comment: Ah ok that worked! The div was not changing as it was still going into the if statement when it was not supposed to. So I added the following var element = document.getElementById(editableId); and then changed the If statement: if(element.isContentEditable) { and then it worked perfectly! However, the button is not changing to "Save"

Comment: For the button use `clicked.html('Save');`

Comment: Works like a charm!! I will be marking your answer as the answer! Thanks so much! Just a quick question, is there a way that If I click on a different edit button, that the current one/all the others changes back to "Edit" ?

Comment: Before `clicked.html('Save');` add `$('.edit-button').html('Edit');` all elements with `.edit-button` class will have _Edit_ value and then you will change value of clicked element to _Save_

Comment: Of coarse! Thanks! One LAST thing, I see now that the previous div is editable when I click on it, is there a way to also make all the divs not editable when I click on the edit button ?

Comment: No worries, I found what I was looking for :) var editable_elements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");
for(var i=0; i<editable_elements.length; i++)
    editable_elements[i].setAttribute("contentEditable", false);

Did the job perfectly! Thanks again for all your help!!